# How do you change the deviceName and deviceType in the Thingsboard Rule Engine?

Tags: thingsboard

Making a rule and manually change the incoming "deviceName" and "deviceType" in the metadata afterwards doing a "Save Timeseries" doesn't change the deviceName property. Is there some other node in the Rule Engine that I need to use?

Answer (score 0):

Try Script Transformation Node